# If $ABC$ is a right angled triangle at $C$ then prove that $a^n+b^n<c^n$ for all $n>2$

Tags: inequality, triangle-inequality

> If $ABC$ is a right angled triangle at $C$ then prove that $a^n+b^n<c^n$ for all $n>2$

This is an olympiad book problem. I know that $a+b>c$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$, $a^n+b^n≠c^n$ for all $n>2$,  and $(a+b)^n>c^n$ but I cant find a way to put these together and prove the above, may be I am not hitting up the right approach .......Need help.

Answer (score 6):

Well, we know $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ and we know $a\lt c$ and $b\lt c$ so we can write this:

$$a^n+b^n = a^2a^{n-2}+b^2b^{n-2} \leq a^2(\max\{a, b\})^{n-2}+b^2(\max\{a, b\})^{n-2} \lt (a^2+b^2)c^{n-2} = c^n$$

Comment: Very simple , Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If $n>2$, the unit ball of the norm $\|(x,y)\|_2=(|x|^2+|y|^2)^{1/2}$  is contained in the unit ball of $\|(x,y)\|_n=(|x|^n+|y|^n)^{1/n}$, and there are only four common points: $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$. Therefore, if $(a/c)^2+(b/c)^2=1$,
then the point $(a/c,b/c)$ lies in the *interior* of the unit ball of $\|\cdot\|_n$, because $a,b,c$ are all non-zero.

Comment: This seems circular to me. How do you prove that the unit ball is contained within the other, without having already proving this inequality?

Comment: @CalvinLin Holder's inequality implies this inequality, not implied by it.

Comment: Ah yes. We can use much heavier machinery like Holder's inequality to prove the fact about the unit ball.